# MyClass obj = "String" is this possible in java?

Tags: java

Is it possible to assign a string literal to an object in Java?
Like this:

```
String strLiteral = "String value"; 
MyClass obj = "String"; // Is this possible
```

Comment: No, you can't specify user-defined conversions.

Comment: have your tried it? did it work? what was your error?

Comment: `String strLiteral = "String value"` is possible, `MyClass obj = "String"` won't work since as Jon Skeet already stated you can't specify user-defined conversions. The closest you could get would be something like `MyClass obj = new MyClass("String")`.

Comment: This feels like an X/Y problem: You want to do X, you think assigning a string to `obj` (Y) will let you do X, so you've asked about Y. What's X?

Comment: How can i create own String like class in java? ie, String literals will create in String pool, We can assign String literal as object also.

Comment: @NineeshCV: *"String literals will create in String pool, We can assign String literal as object also."* The strings in the pool **are** objects. All strings are objects in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not trying to assign it to an *object*, you're trying to assign it to a variable of type `MyClass`.

You can do that if `String` is assignment-compatible to that class. For instance:

```
Comparable c = "Foo";
```

is fine, because `String` is assignment-compatible with `Comparable`, since `String` implements `Comparable`. The object is still a `String`, it's just that we're accessing it through a variable of type `Comparable`. (See [*What does it mean to “program to an interface”?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) for more on that concept.)

You can't do:

```
class Foo {
}

// Doesn't work
Foo f = "Foo";
```

because `String` is not assignment-compatible with `Foo`.

Comment: Thank you, How can I create own String like class in java?

Comment: @NineeshCV: Simply by creating it, like any other class. But there are a couple of things about `String` you can't duplicate: 1. You can't add new literal forms to Java, those have to be defined at the specification level (and all the levels deriving from it). 2. You can't override `+` for your class.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot, because `MyClass` is not a superclass of `String`.

One option is to make a static factory method `fromString` on your class and use like so:

```
MyClass obj = MyClass.fromString("String");
```

In this method, you can define the conversion from a `String` to a `MyClass`.

Answer (score -1):

String is Final Class you cannot extend string class and could not able to create subclass. So you cannot assign a string to different class name.

Comment: `String` being `final` is irrelevant, you can't assign a superclass reference to a subclass variable anyway (without a cast).